# PHP date create always returns false

Tags: php

I'm trying to create new date in PHP but it always returns false no matter what I try.
What returns false:

```
date_create($request->start_date);
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y H:i:s', $request->start_date);
date_create_from_format("d/M/Y H:i:s",$request->start_date);
```

and `$request->start_date` looks like this `"25/04/2017 20:30:00"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $request->start_date);
```

The `M` you were using is for a textual representation of a month, not numeric ([see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php))

Comment: yeah that fixed it. Thanks